# Android OpenGL equivalent of Matrix.mapPoints()

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am converting a 2D android game into an open GL android game and part of my collision detection system depends on mapping some points based off some matrix. I need the equivalent of mapPoints which will take in an array of x,y,z triplets and return the values when they've been put into the matrix coordinate system.

Comment: Uh...you mean like...just multiplying the points by the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method:

`android.opengl.Matrix.multiplyMV(float[] resultVec, int resultVecOffset, float[] lhsMat, int lhsMatOffset, float[] rhsVec, int rhsVecOffset)`

Answer (score 0):

The linke below has the correct answer. Basically there is a static method inside the android.opengl.Matrix object.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html